# Error Cannot convert from int to boolean

Tags: java

I am facing Error Cannot convert from int to boolean, Here is the code where i am getting this problem.

```
private boolean seeDB()
  {
    int i = 1;
    SQLiteDatabase localSQLiteDatabase = null;
    try
    {
      localSQLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, 1);
      localSQLiteDatabase = localSQLiteDatabase;
      label01: 
          if (localSQLiteDatabase != null)
        localSQLiteDatabase.close();
      if (localSQLiteDatabase != null);
      while (true)
      {
        return i;
      }
    }
    catch (SQLiteException localSQLiteException)
    {
      break label01;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You have declared that this method returns a boolean.  But you are returning `i`, which you have declared as an int.

Comment: You're returning an `int`.  You're supposed to be returning a `boolean`.  Either change the return type from `boolean` to `int` or adjust your logic.  (And judging from the loop that only ever runs once,  and the random label expression - I would think that the latter would be a stronger approach.)

Comment: you can change return type to int (or) based on value of i return a boolean (true or false)

Comment: Also, you might want to reconsider having `return i` wrapped up in `while(true)` - there doesn't seem to be much point, as no looping is going to occur.  I also think that you don't want to have the semicolon on the line above `while(true)`.  Lastly, the line that says `localSQLiteDatabase = localSQLiteDatabase;` does nothing.

Comment: This has to be one of the worst pieces of code I've ever seen. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method return type `boolean`

```
private boolean seeDB()
```

and you are returning  `int`

```
 return i;
```

So that error is correct.

Another error is

```
  if (localSQLiteDatabase != null);   <--
```

That condition  ends there with that extra `;`

Finally you should re think about your logic, tell us what you are trying to do. You may get a better logic.

Here some idea of what you are doing

```
 private boolean closeDB()
      {
        SQLiteDatabase localSQLiteDatabase = null;
        try
        {
          localSQLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, 1);
          if (localSQLiteDatabase != null){
            localSQLiteDatabase.close();
            return true; // opended DB closed 
          }else{
            return false;//  no connections opened right now.
          }

        }
        catch (SQLiteException localSQLiteException){
      }
```

Comment: beaten me withe few seconds, +1 :-)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ please can you show me how my method should look like

Comment: Oh my bad luck, i found my mistake

Comment: @AbrahimNeil Great !!. Glad to help. But never fail to explain your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your method is suppose to return boolean :

```
private boolean seeDB()
```

but you are returning an int

```
    return i;
```

i is defined as int

```
int i = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well yes, the problem is here:

```
while (true)
{
    return i;
}
```

The method is declared to return `boolean`, but `i` is declared as an `int`. That's not going to work. You need to either change the return type to `int`, or work out when you want to return `true` and when you want to return `false`.

Additionally:

- The value of `i` is *always* going to be 1
- You're returning it in a `while(true)` loop, which is pointless
- Your approach of breaking to a label in a `catch` block is invalid as far as I'm aware.
- You've got a pointless `if` statement here:

  ```
  if (localSQLiteDatabase != null);
  ```

What are you actually trying to *achieve* with this code? It looks like it's just badly-decompiled code, to be honest. I suggest you start again from scratch, work out exactly what you're trying to achieve, and proceed from there. Your current code is so confused as to be unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

your method return type is boolean value and you are trying to return int value

Answer (score 0):

If i is a type of flag then it should be of type boolean and not int. Your method's return type is booelan. Any specific reasons for using int type for i.

-Ria